# MFC SDI Application without a default "New Document" on Startup

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

My application is an SDI with multiple views. By default, it creates a new document when the application starts. I want to modify this behavior so that a new document is created only when user explicitly clicks on "New". Or at least mimic this behavior. Any ideas? I am using Visual Studio 2008 with MFC feature pack. I googled and found some solution to this problem in an old [***MS Journal article***](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S204D.aspx). But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work now. Any workarounds or solutions? In short, I need to differentiate between framework call to OnFileNew() and User Click on New.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the frame work calls OnFileNew?  If so, set a breakpoint in the function then trace back to where its called.  If necessary, override the function calling it and do everything the same except the creation of a new document.  That should do it.